# If $X$ is a normed space and $Y \subset X$, show $\max\limits_{\substack{f \in X^*,\\ \|f\|\leq 1,\,f|_{Y}=0\;}} |f(x)|=\inf\limits_{y \in Y}|x-y|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Y \subset X$ a subspace of normed space $X$. Show that
$$\displaystyle \max_{f \in X^*, \ ||f||\leq 1, \ f|_{Y}=0} |f(x)|=\inf_{y \in Y}|x-y|.$$

Comment: I'm trying to solve inequalities separately

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem.  This theorem comes in several flavours, and one states that given a point $x \in X$ there is a functional $\phi \in X^*$ for which $\phi |_Y = 0$ (provided $Y$ is a closed subspace), $\phi(x) = \inf\{ \| x- y \| : y \in Y\}$, and $\|\phi\| = 1$.

Now we just need to show for any other functional $\psi \in X^*$ with $\|\psi\| \le 1$ and $\psi|_Y = 0$ we have $\|\psi(x)\| \le \inf\{ \|x - y\| : y \in Y\}$.

Notice that for all $y \in Y$: $$\|\psi(x)\| = \|\psi(x - y)\| \le \|x-y\|.$$

The equality follows since $\psi(y)=0$ and the inequality follows from the bound on the norm of $\psi$.

Comment: By the way, I added that $Y$ is a closed subspace to the hypothesis.  I believe the claim is false otherwise.

Comment: Also this would follow trivially if we were in a Hilbert Space.  In a Hilbert space we could take the projection onto $Y$, $P$, and make an operator $Q = I - P$ which is the projection onto the orthogonal complement of $P$.  The problem is that in a Banach space, we no longer have orthogonality and inner products.  The Hahn Banach theorems allow us to make ``mock" projections in a Banach space.